# How to reset a string variable after for js

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox, checkboxlist

How to reset a string variable after for, I want to insert through innerHTML the selected value from the pressed checkbox, by pressing the button in . But I don't understand how best to reset the variable, but it wouldn't duplicate the past values + the present ones.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox1">carWashing</label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="carWashing" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1">
   </div>  
   <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox2">suspensionDiagnostics</label>
       <input type="checkbox"  value="suspensionDiagnostics id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2">
    </div>  
    <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox3">replacingFilters</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="replacingFilters" name="checkbox3">
    </div>  
</div>
<button class="btn" id="btn"></button>

<div class="l">
    <ul class="ul" id="ul">

    </ul>
</div>

<script>
let ul = document.getElementById("ul")
let check1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1")
let check2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2")
let check3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3")
let sumLi=''
let checkboxesAll = new Array(check1,check2,check3)
//let checkboxesAll = new Array (document.getElementsByName('checkbox'));
console.log(checkboxesAll)

function start() {
  for (let index = 0; index < checkboxesAll.length; index++) {
     if (checkboxesAll[index].checked) {
         sumLi+='<li>'+ checkboxesAll[index].value + '</li>'
     } else {
         console.log('не нажат')
     }
  }
  console.log(sumLi)
  const arr=sumLi.split("</li>")
  console.log(sumLi)

   ul.innerHTML+=sumLi
 }

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = start;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need

but you cant empty your variable at the end by doing`sumLi = ""` this
or you cant declare the variable inside for loop so every time it refreshes

> option 1

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox1">carWashing</label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="carWashing" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1">
   </div>  
   <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox2">suspensionDiagnostics</label>
       <input type="checkbox"  value="suspensionDiagnostics id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2">
    </div>  
    <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox3">replacingFilters</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="replacingFilters" name="checkbox3">
    </div>  
</div>
<button class="btn" id="btn"></button>

<div class="l">
    <ul class="ul" id="ul">

    </ul>
</div>

<script>
let ul = document.getElementById("ul")
let check1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1")
let check2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2")
let check3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3")
let sumLi=''
let checkboxesAll = new Array(check1,check2,check3)
//let checkboxesAll = new Array (document.getElementsByName('checkbox'));
console.log(checkboxesAll)

function start() {
  for (let index = 0; index < checkboxesAll.length; index++) {
     if (checkboxesAll[index].checked) {
         sumLi+='<li>'+ checkboxesAll[index].value + '</li>'
     } else {
         console.log('не нажат')
     }
  }
  console.log(sumLi)
  const arr=sumLi.split("</li>")
  console.log(sumLi)

   ul.innerHTML+=sumLi
   
   // by empty variable every time
   sumLi=""
 }

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = start;
```

> option 2 by declaring inside loop

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox1">carWashing</label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="carWashing" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1">
   </div>  
   <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox2">suspensionDiagnostics</label>
       <input type="checkbox"  value="suspensionDiagnostics id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2">
    </div>  
    <div class="el"></div>  
       <label for="checkbox3">replacingFilters</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="replacingFilters" name="checkbox3">
    </div>  
</div>
<button class="btn" id="btn"></button>

<div class="l">
    <ul class="ul" id="ul">

    </ul>
</div>

<script>
let ul = document.getElementById("ul")
let check1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1")
let check2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2")
let check3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3")

let checkboxesAll = new Array(check1,check2,check3)
//let checkboxesAll = new Array (document.getElementsByName('checkbox'));
console.log(checkboxesAll)

function start() {
  for (let index = 0; index < checkboxesAll.length; index++) {
  let sumLi='';
     if (checkboxesAll[index].checked) {
         sumLi+='<li>'+ checkboxesAll[index].value + '</li>'
     } else {
         console.log('не нажат')
     }
  }
  console.log(sumLi)
  const arr=sumLi.split("</li>")
  console.log(sumLi)

   ul.innerHTML+=sumLi
 }

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = start;
```

have a good day............